# What causes datepicker not loading in rails 3.1.3 with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

We have a very simple use of datepicker in rails 3.1.3 app with jquery. However there are 2 views on which datepicker does not load. On all other views, datepicker loads itself without problem. All js code for datepicker is in application.js file and one of them (not loading) looks like this (with head file):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
   $("#src_plant_src_since").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

Here is the simple form code in view:

```
<%= f.input :src_since, :label => 'start date：', :hint => 'start src date', :as => :string %>
```

What could be the reason causing datepicker loads on one view and not one another? Thanks so much.

Comment: check html source of view where datepciker doesn't load, make sure that all js files in place. After that check javascript console errors, maybe some error blocks execution of js.

Comment: In firebug, there is no error in console. Is there any specific js file loaded for datepicker?

Comment: Here is the script header for the page:    /*!
* jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1
* http://jquery.com/
*
* Copyright 2011, John Resig
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* Includes Sizzle.js
* http://sizzlejs.com/
* Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation
* Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
*
* Date: Mon Nov 21 21:11:03 2011 -0500
*/

Comment: we just found out that the change in application.js could not take effect. This is probably why the modified code for datepicker was not executed at all. The old datepicker code for those two views are not working.

Comment: after deleting application.* under public/assets/, datepicker worked as expected. rake assets:precompile works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gemfile

```
group :assets do
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all 
//= require_tree .
```

Or you can load only the datepicker js. Like:

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

install

```
gem "jquery_datepicker"
```

then this in ur form

```
<%= f.label :date %>
 <%= f.datepicker :date, :dateFormat => 'dd MM, yy',  :showOn => "both", :buttonImage => "../assets/calendar.gif", :buttonImageOnly => true, :changeMonth => true, :changeYear => true, :placeholder => "Click on the textfield/Calender" %><br/>
```

This u should put inside application.html inside your layouts

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```